# How I make chrome page fonts render like the UI?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

After I installed some programs here in an attempt to make Windows render fonts decently on my monitor (cleartype make stuff virtually unreadable), chrome started to render the fonts on the webpages in a extremely thin manner, sometimes so thin that it don't even render an entire pixel (it seemly renders in subpixel size, meaning that I see colour streaks on the font).

But the UI itself renders just fine and looks wonderful. I was wondering how I fix this, it is more Chrome's fault than the the MacType fault, since all other programs are looking just fine, and chrome itself looks fine when it does not use the HTML rendering engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling LCD text antialiasing (`lcd-text-aa`) in `chrome://flags`.

If that doesn't do it, try disabling DirectWrite (`disable-direct-write`).

There are a host of other interesting settings on that flags page that might be worth looking at too.